# My matrix is not the same in visualization and in allocation?

Tags: c, matrix

Being new to C, I wrote a little code to make a tri-diagonal matrix. However I'm at a loss, since this matrix changes between initialization and visualization. Using printf to see the matrix "as on paper", I even printed the indices i and j to check if there was an issue there, but apparently not. I do not understand how A[2, 2] changes from 2 to -1, could you please help me?
Here is the output I have:

```
[0][0]: 2.000000 [0][1]: -1.000000 [0][2]: 0.000000 [0][3]: 0.000000 
[1][0]: -1.000000 [1][1]: 2.000000 [1][2]: -1.000000 [1][3]: 0.000000 
[2][0]: 0.000000 [2][1]: -1.000000 [2][2]: 2.000000 [2][3]: -1.000000 
[3][0]: 0.000000 [3][1]: 0.000000 [3][2]: -1.000000 [3][3]: 2.000000

[0][0]: 0.000000 [0][1]: 0.000000 [0][2]: -1.000000 [0][3]: 2.000000 
[1][0]: 0.000000 [1][1]: 0.000000 [1][2]: -1.000000 [1][3]: 2.000000 
[2][0]: 0.000000 [2][1]: 0.000000 [2][2]: -1.000000 [2][3]: 2.000000 
[3][0]: 0.000000 [3][1]: 0.000000 [3][2]: -1.000000 [3][3]: 2.000000
```

While my code looks like this:

```
float **A;
int i, j = 0;
A_row = (float *)malloc( N * sizeof(float));    
A = (float **)malloc( N * sizeof(float *));

for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    A[i] = A_row;
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        A[i][j] = 0.;   
        if(i == j){A[i][j] = 2.;}
        else if(i == j-1) {A[i][j]=-1;}
        else if(i == j+1) {A[i][j]=-1;}
        printf("[%d][%d]: %f ", i, j, A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//check A
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        printf("[%d][%d]: %f ", i, j, A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I'm really sorry for the trouble.

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit in writing `else if(i == j+1) {A[i][j]=-1;}` in fact it makes the code really ugly an hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the rows in your matrix are the same, they will be equal to the last one.

```
A[i] = A_row
```

should be

```
A[i] = malloc(N * sizeof(float));
```

i.e. allocate `N` `float`s for each row, as you have it you are assigning the "*same space*" for every row. Altering the contents of that space will affect all the rows simultaneously (*or not really, because in fact they are the **same** row*).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, it indeed solved my problem. I will also change one "else if" with a logical "or" as you suggested. And thank you for the explanation too, it makes sense and helps me grasp my mistake ! :D Have a wonderfull week end!